# Excel Alters hyperlink text

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have about 5k cells with unique hyperlinks pertaining to evernote.
an example is shown here A1 = `evernote:///view/70974153/s413/001b41d4-8fd3-416b-b74e-16a06f761b83/001b41d4-8fd3-416b-b74e-16a06f761b83/`

I used excel =Hyperlink(A1,"Link1")
it creates a working hyperlink however it changes link text from `evernote:///view` to `evernote://view`

this works with windows machine but does not work on iDevices and OSX evernote app.

my question is why excel eliminates "/" instead of passing actual text that I want hyperlinked. Is there a work around for it.
I definitely need to have "///" because iOS and OSX devices work with "///" links

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/903876 ?

Comment: SeanC - thanks for sharing, that was helpful but I am stuck at this stage HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Common, in the I do not have 10.0.  I do have 8.0, 9.0 and 14.0 but there is no 10.0